# Android loop insert records

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm stuck at this point and that is: the user selects a start date, for example: (01/01/2014) and an end date (01/01/2015). In this range of dates I enter every month 1 of a record with their dates, then 01/01/2014, 02/01/2014 and so on until the final date. 
I hope I explained myself, this is the code that I have, Thanks for the help.

```
public void diff_date(View v){
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
   String date_in = sdf.format( dateAndTime .getTime() );
    String date_out = sdf.format( dateAndTime1.getTime() );
    int differenza_date = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(date_in), new DateTime(date_out)).getDays();


   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

   cv.put(tabella1Table.DATE, date_in);


    for(int i=1 ; i < differenza_date ; i++){



               }

    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }
```

Comment: ;) i think this question asked before  , i provide you with answer and feed me back if it work with yo or not

Comment: if it works save my life and I will accept your answer. Now I try and see

Comment: :) hope it work for you , and feel free feed me back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this code :

SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(date_in));


    cv.put(tabella1Table.DATE, date_in);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    for(int i=1 ; i < differenza_date ; i++){
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, i);  
    date_in = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    cv.put(tabella1Table.DATE, date_in);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
   }
```